# Can't use wow.js

Tags: function

Well, I tried applying wow.js, but it didn't seem to work for me.

In the hmtl file:

```
<!-- Bootstrap-->
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- WOW.js-->
<scirpt src=js/wow/wow.min.js></scirpt>



<script src="js/customjs"></script>
```

In the js file:

```
$(function(){
    new WOW().init(); 
});
```

```
'$' was used before it was defined. $(function(){
2   
Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.  $(function(){
2   
Expected exactly one space between ')' and '{'. $(function(){
2   
Missing space between ')' and '{'.  $(function(){
4   
Missing 'use strict' statement. new WOW().init();
4   
Expected 'new' at column 5, not column 15.  new WOW().init();
4   
'WOW' was used before it was defined.   new WOW().init();
 ESLint (2)
2   
ERROR: '$' is not defined. [no-undef]   $(function(){
4   
ERROR: 'WOW' is not defined. [no-undef] new WOW().init();
```